# AWS S3 Put not getting picked up by Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I have a lambda job that is detecting a s3 put to Bucket A and moving it to Bucket B. I have another lambda job that detects S3 put to the bucket B and does some actions with that file.

For some reason, the automatic put to bucket B by bucket A lambda job is not getting triggered. If I upload manually to bucket B, the lambda job does get triggered.

It is the exact same code, and presumably the same action of S3 put, and I have no idea why this may be happening.

Do you guys have any inputs? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is the exact same code, and presumably the same action of S3 put

Nope.

There are 5 different events, representing 4 different ways to create an object, and a wildcard.

```
s3:ObjectCreated:Put
s3:ObjectCreated:Post
s3:ObjectCreated:Copy
s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload

s3:ObjectCreated:*
```

You almost always want that last one, unless you deliberately want to restrict which actions fire events... but it sounds like you tied the event to the first one.  "Moving" an object from one bucket to another us usually done with the Copy operation... but not always.  Go with the wildcard unless you have a specific reason not to.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations